ConTeXt: excessive line spacing with columns and mathalignment
\starttext
  \subject{without columns}
  \startformula
    \startmathalignment[n=3]
      \NC a \NC = b+c \NC = d+e \NR
      \NC a \NC = b+c \NC = d+e \NR
      \NC a \NC = b+c \NC = d+e \NR
    \stopmathalignment
  \stopformula


  \subject{with columns}
\startcolumns[n=2]
    \startmathalignment[n=3]
      \NC a \NC = b+c \NC = d+e \NR
      \NC a \NC = b+c \NC = d+e \NR
      \NC a \NC = b+c \NC = d+e \NR
    \stopmathalignment

    \startmathalignment[n=3]
      \NC v \NC = w+x \NC = y+z \NR
      \NC v \NC = w+x \NC = y+z \NR
      \NC v \NC = w+x \NC = y+z \NR
    \stopmathalignment
\stopcolumns
\stoptext

As shown in the attached figure, when mathalignment is used between [start|stop]columns, excessive line spacing is produced. Is there a way to avoid that behavior?


Putting \divide\baselineskip by 4  \advance\baselineskip by -1pt inside of \startcolumns fixes the problem for arbitrary values of \baselineskip (\setupinterlinespace[…]), but I'm not sure why that fixes it. Maybe a ConTeXt bug?

When you do \startcolumns you go into grid mode as well. We have not yet configured math to adapt with the grid (not done in a day). By default the interlinespace in formulas are set to .125baselineskip, and when you are in grid mode that snaps to full lines. You can experiment with (and are a bit on your own at the moment)
\setupformula[interlinespace=0pt]

But maybe, if you do not need the grid, pagecolumns are a safer option at the moment (\startpagecolumns and \stoppagecolumns). These, on the other hand, don't mix with single column mode.

It's in the details §4 discusses formulas on grids, but as you said it's pretty tricky to get good results. And in addition to page columns, there's also mixed columns (\startmixedcolumns), column sets (\startcolumnset), and simple columns (\startsimplecolumns), but I have no idea if those still work.
